# Can't run composer command in cmd

Tags: php, composer-php

Successfully install composer with their instruction but I can't check composer version. I also add path in environment. Which things left that I need to do?

User Variables

[image]

System Variables

[image]

Command line
[image]

Comment: `-v` sets composer to verbose mode but you aren't giving it any commands so there's nothing to show. If you want the version, it's `-V` (capital "V") or `--version`. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#command-line-interface-commands

Comment: or simply use composer

Comment: I used them but it does not show nothing like in my pic

Comment: @Mr.Pyae it's difficult to understand what you're saying. From reading your question, it sounds like you are running `composer -v` and not seeing anything (as per your screenshot). What happens if you run `composer --version`?

Comment: when i run composer --version, it show nothing. Same as command line pic in question

Comment: What do you see when you do "echo %PATH%"? Are you able to successfully run composer -V when navigating to the directory where the composer.bat is located?

Answer (score 0):

Check if using this command works for you:

`php C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar -v`

If this is working and there is a missing `composer.bat` file in `C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin` you'll have to create it manually with this content:

```
@echo off
php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*
```

Then you'll be able to use `composer -v` instead of `php C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar -v` in your Command Prompt.

I'm assuming that you could execute php scripts and you already added the correct path to your system, because if `composer.bat` is not missing and you didn't add the path to your php executables, then this is the reason for this composer issue in the first place.